# Is istio.io organized as a non-profit consortium?

Tags: istio

Seems to be, but nothing at https://github.com/istio/community says it outright.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: The answer's still useful.

Comment: Lots of questions that are inappropriate for SO are useful.  But that doesn't mean they belong here.

Answer (score -1):

According to Crunchbase istio is [for profit](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/istio#section-overview). I have no problem investing my time learning something created by a company, it's just useful to know where it comes from and why.